# Reloading page when audio ends

Tags: html, reload

I'm trying to have a web page automatically reload itself when an audio file has stopped playing. I've tried playing around with the  tag w/ the onended parameter to no avail. Please help.

```html
<html>
<body>
<center>
<embed src="1.wav" width="0" height="0"></embed>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AD 2015 you should be using `<audio />` element and its `ended` event. http://jsfiddle.net/dcaeexd3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `<audio />` element and its `ended` event.

```
<audio src="1.wav" onended="window.location.reload()" />
```

[Audio element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

[Media events on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcaeexd3/)

BTW if you want to reload just so it loops then... there are better ways to do it. If you want to play a random track on each load it could also be done without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as [pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879/pawel) mentioned, You should use `<audio>` tag instead.

Then You could do something like that using [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) and JS.

It might look like this:

```
var audio_element = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
audio_element.addEventListener("ended",
    function() {
      document.location.reload(true); 
    }, true);
```

Bare in mind, there are better ways for changing or looping audio file.